# How to invoke Action<String^> via Parallel::For

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, parallel.for

I would like to invoke an `Action<String^` via `Parallel::For` but get the error below.

My code:

```
Action<String^> ^act =    gcnew Action<String^>(this, &Form1::loadFileInternam);

System::Threading::Tasks::Parallel::For(1, 16, act);
```

```
void loadFileInternam(String^ fn)
{
}
```

The error I get:

> Error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2665   'System::Threading::Tasks::Parallel::For': none of the 8
> overloads could convert all the argument
> types ddddd   C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\repos\new_c++\Text editor -
> Copy\CppCLR_WinformsProject1 - Copy - Copy - Copy (2) - Copy
> (2)\Form1.h   1620

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem:**

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-7.0), according to the list of overloads `Parallel::For` support several types of `Action`, but none of them accepts a `String` argument.

**A Solution:**

It is not clear what you actually intended the `String` to be when `loadFileInternam` is invoked by `Parallel::For`, since you haven't supplied any context.

But the type of `Action` that might suit your needs is: `Action<Int32>`.
This `Action` will be passed an `Int32` from the range you passed to `Parallel::For`, i.e. **1..16** (**not** inclusive).
You can use this index to select the relevant string to pass to `loadFileInternam`.

**Something like:**

```
ref class Form1
{
    // The actual method you need to invoke:
    void loadFileInternam(String ^ fn)
    {
    }

    // The Action used by Parallel::For (will be called for [1,16) in this case):
    void loadFileInternamHelper(Int32 idx)
    {
        String^ s = "aaa";  // determine s according to idx
        loadFileInternam(s);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Action<Int32>^ act = gcnew Action<Int32>(this, &Form1::loadFileInternamHelper);
        System::Threading::Tasks::Parallel::For(1, 16, act);
    }
};
```

Comment: loadFileInternam accept String^ as file name.

Comment: Yes, and `loadFileInternamHelper` is indeed calling `loadFileInternam` with a `String^`. But you need to determine this `String^` according to the index produced by the `Parallel::For` (`Parallel::For` cannot determine it for you).